# SharePoint 2010 Calendar Syncing with Outlook 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am getting an error when trying to sync some calendars with Outlook.  The error is

"Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80070005): 'You do not have permission to view this SharePoint List (Site Name - Calendar Name).  Contact the SharePoint site administrator. HTTP 302'"

This error is intermittent (removing the calendar from Outlook and re-syncing it sometimes resolves it temporarily) and does not effect all users at the same time.
I have full control of the site as well as the calendar in question. I have tried breaking permission inheritance and setting unique permissions on the calendar with no change. I have checked AAM and all is correct (site is accessed the via the same URL internally and externally)

Our site uses both Forms Based Authentication and Windows Authentication.  This issue is experience by users using AD (have not tried any FBA users).

Comment: which version of exchange and outlook are you using

Comment: please make the question title more descriptive

Comment: Exchange 2007 and Outlook 2010

Answer (score 1):

Setup the URL for default and intranet (I know, I know) - just try it. We thought internet was right too - but kept hitting our heads against the wall. If it breaks something, try setting the value for all 3 zones - default, internet and intranet... may the luck be with you.

Answer (score 0):

- Go into SharePoint Central
  Administration
- Go to Operations  Under Global
  Configuration, select Alternate
  access mappings
- Choose your Alternate Access Mapping
  Collection from the dropdown (e.g.
  SharePoint - 80)
- Make the Default zone your new DNS
  name, including if it's SSL'ed or not
  (e.g. http://portal.company.com or
  https://portal.company.com)

[They were having the same errors](http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--setup-upgrade-administration-operation/task-sharepoint-reported-error-0x80070005--you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-sharepoint-14262.shtml)

Comment: AAM is set up correctly.  All requests are done to the same URL internally and externally.  Default url is set to _https://sp.company.com

Comment: it could do something with your webconfig file according to this link

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/804ae87b-cac6-4e24-9bc6-b8573abfc95c